# World Environment HDRI vs. Sphere w/ HDRI texture over entire scene... is there a difference/advantage?

Tags: hdri, world

Is there an advantage, or a difference, between adding an environment texture to the World, vs. adding the same environment texture to a sphere and simply scaling it up to surround your scene?

The advantage of using a sphere is that you can easily rotate the HDRI without having to use Texture Mapping and Coordinates nodes.

I'm just curious if Blender processes the light information on the scene differently coming from a sphere vs. the World.

Comment: I may be wrong but I think it's the same, except your camera location and zoom won't be taken into account with an HDRI. Also, having to plug some nodes is not so tedious, you also need to do it for a sphere

Comment: The advantage is that you don't need to create a new geometry (the sphere) to add the HDRI, you basically created a Studio to light your object or scene

Comment: Thanks @moonboots and you're right it's not too tedious, but I do prefer to use a sphere.  I shoot scenes and HDRI's in the middle of those scenes, then I rebuild the scene in the viewport.  It is a lot easier for me to match up the background (HDRI) to the foreground plate by simply rotating a sphere until I get it exact.  I just wasn't sure what the implication would be in terms of how the scene is rendered using the sphere as a World environment.  Cheers.